# How can I add additional Test projects to the "Create Unit Tests" context menu in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, xunit

How can I add existing Test projects to the right click context menu for "Creating unit tests" in Visual Studio 2015?

It only shows one of the test projects (the project was created using the right click context action). The other project was created using the new project wizard and is not shown.

[image: Missing Projects]
[image: Available Unit Test Projects]

Is there a way to add existing unit test projects to the dropdown list?

Answer (score 1):

I have not pinned down which step-s are mandatory, but below are the steps which allowed me to add an existing project to the Intellitest "Create Unit Test" list :

- Reference `Microsoft.Pex.Framework` assembly
- Add "PexAssemblyInfo.cs" file in Properties project's special folder. Edit accordingly.
- In .csproj file, add `<TestProjectType>"UnitTest"</TestProjectType>` tag, in `<PropertyGroup>` node
- In .csproj file, add `<IsCodedUITest>False</IsCodedUITest>` tag, in `<PropertyGroup>` node *(probably not required)*
- In .csproj file, add "{3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB}" (Test project type) to `<ProjectTypeGuids>` tag

---

**Edit:** Sample PexAssemblyInfo.cs content

```
using Microsoft.Pex.Framework.Coverage;
using Microsoft.Pex.Framework.Creatable;
using Microsoft.Pex.Framework.Instrumentation;
using Microsoft.Pex.Framework.Settings;
using Microsoft.Pex.Framework.Validation;

// Microsoft.Pex.Framework.Settings
[assembly: PexAssemblySettings(TestFramework = "xunit-2.0")]

// Microsoft.Pex.Framework.Instrumentation
[assembly: PexAssemblyUnderTest("{YOUR-PROJECT-NAME}")]
[assembly: PexInstrumentAssembly("System.Runtime.Extensions")]
[assembly: PexInstrumentAssembly("System.Linq.Expressions")]
[assembly: PexInstrumentAssembly("System.Threading")]
[assembly: PexInstrumentAssembly("System.Reflection.Extensions")]
[assembly: PexInstrumentAssembly("System.Reflection")]
[assembly: PexInstrumentAssembly("System.Diagnostics.Debug")]
[assembly: PexInstrumentAssembly("System.Runtime")]
[assembly: PexInstrumentAssembly("System.Threading.Tasks")]
[assembly: PexInstrumentAssembly("System.Collections")]

// Microsoft.Pex.Framework.Creatable
[assembly: PexCreatableFactoryForDelegates]

// Microsoft.Pex.Framework.Validation
[assembly: PexAllowedContractRequiresFailureAtTypeUnderTestSurface]
[assembly: PexAllowedXmlDocumentedException]

// Microsoft.Pex.Framework.Coverage
[assembly: PexCoverageFilterAssembly(PexCoverageDomain.UserOrTestCode, "System.Runtime.Extensions")]
[assembly: PexCoverageFilterAssembly(PexCoverageDomain.UserOrTestCode, "System.Linq.Expressions")]
[assembly: PexCoverageFilterAssembly(PexCoverageDomain.UserOrTestCode, "System.Threading")]
[assembly: PexCoverageFilterAssembly(PexCoverageDomain.UserOrTestCode, "System.Reflection.Extensions")]
[assembly: PexCoverageFilterAssembly(PexCoverageDomain.UserOrTestCode, "System.Reflection")]
[assembly: PexCoverageFilterAssembly(PexCoverageDomain.UserOrTestCode, "System.Diagnostics.Debug")]
[assembly: PexCoverageFilterAssembly(PexCoverageDomain.UserOrTestCode, "System.Runtime")]
[assembly: PexCoverageFilterAssembly(PexCoverageDomain.UserOrTestCode, "System.Threading.Tasks")]
[assembly: PexCoverageFilterAssembly(PexCoverageDomain.UserOrTestCode, "System.Collections")]
```

Comment: What's the PexAssemblyInfo.cs for?

Comment: It defines Pex-specific settings, such as assembly under test, referenced assembly, and such. You can copy/paste one such from an automatically generated Intellitest project.

Comment: I cant find an Assembly that is named PEX or similiar. Also creating a Xunit test project via the wizard does not create a PexAssemblyInfo.cs file.
And just adding the TestProjectType and IsCodedUiTest lines does not make the projekt show in the wizard.

Comment: The exact assembly name is "Microsoft.Pex.Framework". If you look into Intellitest generated project references, it will be listed. The "PexAssemblyInfo.cs" file is under the "Properties" folder of said project.

Comment: Well ok, but I am not trying to create IntelliTests, just the normal "Create Unit Tests".

Comment: Indeed, my bad. The easiest way to achieve your design appears to be comparing two projects : one automatically generated using "Create Unit Test", and the other one being your own test project.